# laravel ajax form and checkbox

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

Hi I have a form in laravel with a checkbox inside, i send datas via ajax
This is my html

```
      <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" name="customSwitch1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Cartaceo</label>
      </div>
```

i cannot understand why the checkbox is sending always ON...I need to manage on/off with javascript?
Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved with javascript / jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '#customSwitch1', function(event) { 
  if (this.checked == true) {
    $("#customSwitch1").val("on");
  }
  else {
    $("#customSwitch1").val("off");
  }
});
```